# Project Euler problem #3 why won't my code print my answer?

Tags: python

I am using two for loops to count down from 600851475143 to find the highest prime number. The problem is [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3). The code works for a smaller number like the one given in the question, but for 600851475143 after running for a minute it ends without giving an answer. Is the problem the number of operations being too many?

```
x = 600851475143
y = x-1
answer = 0

for i in range(y, 1, -1):
    if x % i == 0:
        k = i-1
        for j in range(k, 1, -1):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
            elif j == 2 and i % j == 0:
                answer = i
    if answer != 0:
        break
print(answer)
```

Comment: Did you try putting a print statement in the loop and debugging this? What did you get?

Comment: Remember Euler was a mathematician. Brute force doesn't work for most of the problems. You need to do a little mathematical thinking to reduce the amount of calculations the computer does.

Comment: Looking for a divisor is faster if you start from the low end, as at that side you can expect  the most of them. If you start from the top (from x-1) you are sure to *not* find any until you reached y/2. Secondly, when you *do* find one, make sure to actually make the division, so that your problem gets smaller.

Comment: It seems the problem is the number of computations. I'll try to thinak of a way to optimise my code. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you iterate your loop almost 1..600851475143 * 1..600851475142 times. Therefore you should optimize your code.

You can glance over this link to get an idea : https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/BasicMath/Prime/Algorithm-PrimeFactor.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using a for loop to iterate through numbers starting from 600851475143 going down; this is extremely slow. I suspect the program is taking too long to run. All project euler programs should be able to be completed within 2 minutes of running. Try optimising your algorithm so it runs faster.